# How to store a key and multiple values array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, key-value

I have more than two arrays containing keys and values and the task is to store it as a single entity in the form key => value in JavaScript like this. For two arrays, my code is working fine, but what can I do for three or more arrays? How do I pair all these with keys?

```
5 => Geeks => Value 3
2 => for =>Value 3
3 => Geeks =>Value 3
6 => Course =>Value 3
10 => Algorithm =>Value 3
```

This code is fine if there are two arrays:

```
<script> 
    // An array of keys
    var keys = [5, 2, 3, 6, 10];
      
    // An array of values
    var values = ["Geeks", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];
      
    // Map created
    var map = new Map();
      
    // Using loop to insert key
    // value in map
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        map.set(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
      
    // Printing
    for (var key of map.keys()) {
        document.write(key + " => " + map.get(key) + "</br>")
    }
</script>
```

However, if there are three or more arrays, what do we need to do in JavaScript?

```
 <script> 
    // An array of keys
    var keys = [5, 2, 3, 6, 10];
      
    // An array of values
    var values = ["Geeks", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];
      
    var values2 = ["value 2", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];
    var values3 = ["value 3", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];
    // Map created
    var map = new Map();
      
    // Using loop to insert key
    // value in map
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        map.set(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
      
    // Printing
    for (var key of map.keys()) {
        document.write(key + " => " + map.get(key) + "</br>")
    }
  
</script>
```

I need answer like this

```
5 => Geeks => Value 3
2 => for =>Value 3
3 => Geeks =>Value 3
6 => Course =>Value 3
10 => Algorithm =>Value 3
```

Comment: What does `3 => Geeks =>Value 3` mean?  And how to you get that from the input data.   I can't understand what your question means.  I understand how 3 is associated with "Geeks" as they are each in the `[2]` position in the first two arrays.  But where does the `=> value 3` come from?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have the data structure you want，but you can do it like this：

```js
// An array of keys
let keys = [5, 2, 3, 6, 10];

// An array of values
let values = ["Geeks", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];

let values2 = ["value 2", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];
let values3 = ["value 3", "for", "Geeks", "Course", "Algorithm"];

// Map created
let map = new Map();

// Using loop to insert key
// value in map
keys.forEach((key, i) => {
  let vals = [values[i], values2[i], values3[i]];
  map.set(keys[i], vals);
});

for (let key of map.keys()) {
  console.log(key + map.get(key).reduce((pre, val) => pre + " => " + val, ""));
}
```